# I can't insert icons from the drawable folder

Tags: android

I am trying to insert an icon into a FAB from  the drawable folder but Android Studio doesn't recognize it. Could you please help me to figure out why it is not working? Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `@android:drawable/favorite`. Instead use `@drawable/favorite`

`@android:drawable/` is for accessing drawable folder packed with the studio.
To use the drawable folder of your project, use `@drawable/`